# How to read csv file with a record which contains comma and double quotes within double quotes

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the example: "ABC","ABC is not "XYZ", but ABC","CDF"

The problem is with the second record it's got comma and double quotes within double quotes.

How to read it with pandas read_csv?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the correct form to put a double quote within a CSV record is by putting a pair of double quotes.

So, if you have on column as `foo "bar" baz` and another as `foo, bar, baz`, the resulting line in the CSV would be:
`"foo ""bar"" baz","foo, bar, baz"`

If the CSV file isn't formatted like that, it may be malformed, and may either necessitate being regenerated to be within spec, or, if that's unfeasible, necessitate some custom massaging before being fed into a CSV parser.

Where was this CSV taken from?
Was it properly generated?
Could you please give us a more complete example?

BTW, you may want to read the CSV spec: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180